# Angular viewport watch not reducing the number of watches

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I am using the Angular viewport watch directive as per the instructions on https://github.com/shahata/angular-viewport-watch. The application I have is based on Angular 1.4.9.

I have a large number of items (or cards), and each card has many watches. The visible number of cards at any time is very few. However, with or without the Angular viewport watch directive, the number of watches remains the same. I feel certain I have used the directive correctly and have added the JS files and the module dependency. I also cleared my cache and such. I see no console errors either. This is on Chrome.

I am checking someone has used the Angular viewport watch directive recently, and if it worked for them. Any tips or tricks are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't reduce the number of watchers, but it disables the ones that are outside the viewport so the total time spent by processing them is reduced.

Legitimate ways to lower the number of watchers would include the use of bind-once, reducing the number of expressions, or using virtual rendering.

One example of virtual lists is Angular Material's virtual-repeat:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat